# Pass event from class C through class B to class A

Tags: c#, class, events, subclass

I have Class A which implements a large number of instances of Class B.
Class B encapsulates an instance of Class C.

Class C raises events which need to be handled by Class A.
Class A does not need to know about Class C.
Class C is passing back performance based statistics which A then needs to coalesce.

How do I create the events in Class B and connect them so that Class A can subscribe to Class B's events and receive the events from Class C?

Comment: sorry?  Class A *implements a large number of instances of Class B*?  What does that mean exactly? Provide some code please

Answer (score 28):

An event is nothing more than a pair of methods wrapping a delegate field. You can override the default implementation of the add & remove methods in `ClassB` to pass the value straight to the event in `ClassC`:

```
public class ClassB
{
    private ClassC m_C = new ClassC();

    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { m_C.MyEvent += value; }
        remove { m_C.MyEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```